# Problem installing cover version

Tags: itunes, mac, plugins, lyrics

I tried installing the visualizer plugin Cover Version with my new mac with OS Sierra. I followed the instructions and put the file in the itunes plugin folder, but it doesn't show up in iTunes among the Visualizer options. I restarted iTunes (and my Mac) but that didn't help.

Any ideas?

Comment: Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7773/view-song-lyrics-in-itunes?rq=1

Comment: I've just downloaded and installed CoverVersion from http://www.imagomat.de/coverversion/, it still seems to work under Sierra. Did you give it a try?

Comment: @patrix I did, but iTunes does not display Cover View as an option in the Visualizer section.. But then I guess this is a problem with my mac and not with the OS

Comment: I assume you did restart iTunes after copying the bundle to `~/Library/iTunes/iTunes Plugins`?

Comment: @patrix Indeed.. I also restarted my mac

Comment: Do you want to rephrase the question? If it is a local issue, the question as written is primarily a duplicate of the existing question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a stupid mistake on my part; I put the .dmg file in the plugin folder instead of the actual CoverVersion.bundle file. Now it works perfectly